# Low Search - Filtering by Grid count

Tags: low-search, grid

Is it possible to filter entries in Low Search based on the number of rows/count of a specific Grid Field?

For example something like,

`Get all rows whos field X(a Grid field) has a count greater than 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: No.

Slightly longer answer: it could, if you create an extension to cater for it, using Low Search's extension hooks.

Comment: Thanks for the response. This answer does show the direction I am going to take.

Comment: Hi @Low, is the answer the same for simply searching on the content of fields within a grid, such as a filename?

Comment: No, with Low Search, you *can* target a specific Grid column. See http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#field-search